# How to get the value within an option tag in redux-form

Tags: redux-form

In a scenario where I have the select value different from what is shown in the options tags, How can I get the inner value
for example

```
<option value="0">Get this value out</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to extract the option name could you restructure your app to generate the options, then it would be trivial:

```
const options = {
    '0': 'Get this value out',
    '1': 'second value'
}

function submitted(values) {
    const name = options[values.mySelect];
    console.log(`mySelect option name: ${name}`);
}

const Form = reduxForm({ 
    form: 'example',
    onSubmit: submitted
})(props => (
    <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
        <select name="mySelect">
        {Object.keys(options).map(key => (
            <option key={key} value={key}>
                {options[key]}
            </option>
        ))}
        </select>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
))
```

Comment: I can't apply your above method. As I have an API I have destructed to created the select options - this api looks like
`
const options = {
  name: "Name",
  id: 5,
}

I have used the above to create the value and inner text.

Comment: If I understand correctly the API provides options in html?  If so I would  still parse the response to the options object / array.  It sounds like that's what your doing.